# Fixed points of $g^x$ (modulo a prime)

Tags: analytic-number-theory, finite-fields, computational-number-theory

In an explicit construction in combinatorics I need to study the following problem: assume we pick a odd prime number $p$, a generator $g$ of the multiplicative group $(Z/pZ)^{\ast}$.

Question 1: for how many $x\in\{2,\dots,p-2\}$, is it true that $x\equiv g^x\, (p)$.

Question 2: how the previous counting depends on the choice of $g$?

In general I would need indeed the number of solutions of the congruence equation $x\equiv a+g^x\, (p)$ (for fixed $a$), but already the base case $a=0$ is interesting for me.

Comment: Do you know already about https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/brizolis6.pdf ?  Might  be of some use ...

Comment: I did not know about this...but sounds like a good starting point!

Comment: See Theorems 2 and 4 in https://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/n66/n66.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Just to take an arbitrary example, mod $p = 23$ there are $\phi(22) = 10$ primitive roots.  Of those, four ($14, 19, 20, 21$) have no solutions to $x \equiv g^x \mod 23$, two have one, three have two, and one ($11$) has five.

Here, for each of the first $30$ primes, are the number of primitive roots $g$ for which there are no solutions to $x \equiv g^x \mod p$ with $2 \le x \le p-2$:

$$1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 6, 5, 2, 9, 11, 12, 5, 7, 9, 8, 8, 17, 12, 11, 16, 12, 23, 20, 16$$

This sequence does not seem to be in the OEIS (yet).

[EDIT: Although this one is not in OEIS, the number of $g$ for where there **are** solutions is: [OEIS sequence A174407](https://oeis.org/A174407)].

For each prime $< 1000$, the number of such $g$ is at least $1$.

The probability of a random permutation of $[1\ldots p-1]$ being a derangement is approximately $1/e$, so heuristically we might expect about that fraction of the primitive roots to have no solution to $x \equiv g^x \mod p$.

Comment: Maybe we should not include $g=\pm1$ in the discussion, as these are not generators?

Comment: This was just counting generators $g$.

Comment: Dumb (?) question: Is it obvious there should be at least one generator with no fixed points for each odd prime?

Comment: No, it is not at all obvious to me.  Heuristically, if the probability of a generator having no fixed points is about $1/e$, and there are $\phi(p-1)$ generators, the probability that none of them have a fixed point is about $(1-1/e)^{\phi(p-1)}$, and this goes to $0$ rapidly enough that it's not surprising.  But that's not a proof.

Comment: @RobertIsrael The paper by Levin, Pomerance and Soundararajan pointed out in the comment to the question by Lucia actually proves this.

Comment: I thought that paper was proving there is a generator that **does** have a fixed point.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: $\phi(22)=10$ is right. But these $10$ numbers are $\{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21\}$. So, $14$ and $20$ are not among them. Moreover, $1$ is not a generator. Did I miss something? Otherwise, this might mess up the counting you do.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan Yes, you missed something. The generators mod $23$ are not the numbers coprime to $22$, they are $g^k$ where $g$ is one generator and $k$ is coprime to $22$.

Comment: I misunderstood the problem. Sorry and thanks.

Comment: @RobertIsrael what I meant by "this" was the same as you say, i.e., existence of generator with one fixed point.